# Ace Scroll Sync with Preview : Get line height of wrapped lines

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I have a Markdown editor and next to it a Markdown preview. I am trying to add a scroll sync feature like in this demo:

https://markdown-it.github.io/

But according to the author:

> Existing solution in demo is a dirty hack, that can have different bugs in height calculations of textarea content. If you need guaranteed result, it's better to use codemirror / ace instead of textarea. They give better line offsets.

I didn't find similar plugin anywhere so I started recreating the sync algorithm. The problem I stumbled upon is that for the algorithm to work you need the exact height of lines in the editor. This is tricky when lines are soft-wrapped.

So the questions is how to get the line height of a specific line in Ace?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `cursor = {row, column}` you can use `editor.renderer.scrollCursorIntoView(cursor)` to scroll it into view or `editor.renderer.scrollToLine(row)` to scroll with animation.
Note that for animation to work you need to enable it with `editor.setOption("animatedScroll", true)`

Comment: I don't think this answers my question. If you are referring to the entire scroll sync functionality it is more complex then that since different lines from the source are rendered with different height, thus there isn't a simple mapping between source and preview. Look at the example I provided.

Comment: With ace you do not need to keep mapping from scroll position to scroll position, like scrollMap does in the example you provided, instead of that you need to keep aceLineNumber to resultScrollPosition, and let ace figure out it's scrollposition based on line number.